# Template factorial function without template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, template-specialization, factorial

I don't understand the following behavior.

The following code, aimed at computing the factorial at compile time, doesn't even compile:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<int N>
int f() {
  if (N == 1) return 1; // we exit the recursion at 1 instead of 0
  return N*f<N-1>();
}
int main() {
  cout << f<5>() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

and throws the following error:

```
...$ g++ factorial.cpp && ./a.out 
factorial.cpp: In instantiation of ‘int f() [with int N = -894]’:
factorial.cpp:7:18:   recursively required from ‘int f() [with int N = 4]’
factorial.cpp:7:18:   required from ‘int f() [with int N = 5]’
factorial.cpp:15:16:   required from here
factorial.cpp:7:18: fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use ‘-ftemplate-depth=’ to increase the maximum)
    7 |   return N*f<N-1>();
      |            ~~~~~~^~
compilation terminated.
```

whereas, upon adding the specialization for `N == 0` (which the template above doesn't even reach),

```
template<>
int f<0>() {
  cout << "Hello, I'm the specialization.\n";
  return 1;
}
```

the code compiles and give the correct output of, even if the specialization is never used,

```
...$ g++ factorial.cpp && ./a.out 
120
```

Comment: If it can *potentially* be called, it needs to exist.

Comment: In this case `constexpr int f(int N);` (Or `consteval` in c++20) would also work.

Comment: Sidenote: What would be the result of `f<-1>()`? As it is meaningless, I'd prefer unsigned int as template parameter. We wouldn't prevent anybody from writing `f<-1>` (would be converted to huge integer anyway), but at least we'd express right from the start that we actually expect non-negative values only...

Comment: You've gotten an excellent answer that I cannot usefully add to. I just want to state that this is one of the reasons `constexpr` was created.

Comment: To be *mathematically* complete: Factorial of 0 is defined as 1, so you should have `if constexpr(N == 0) return 1; else ...`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The issue here is that your if statement is a run time construct.  When you have

```
int f() {
  if (N == 1) return 1; // we exit the recursion at 1 instead of 0
  return N*f<N-1>();
}
```

the `f<N-1>` is instantiated as it may be called.  Even though the if condition will stop it from calling `f<0>`, the compiler still has to instantiate it since it is part of the function.  That means it instantiates `f<4>`, which instantiates `f<3>`, which instantiates `f<2>`, and on and on it will go forever.

The Pre C++17 way to stop this is to use a specialization for `0` which breaks that chain.  Starting in C++17 with [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If), this is no longer needed.  Using

```
int f() {
  if constexpr (N == 1) return 1; // we exit the recursion at 1 instead of 0
  else return N*f<N-1>();
}
```

guarantees that `return N*f<N-1>();` won't even exist in the `1` case, so you don't keep going down the instantiation rabbit hole.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `f<N>()` *always* instantiates `f<N-1>()` whether that if branch is taken or not. Unless properly terminated, that would create infinite recursion at compile time (i.e. it would attempt instantiating `F<0>`, then `f<-1>`, then `f<-2>` and so on). Obviously you should terminate that recursion somehow.

Apart from `constexpr` solution and specialization suggested by NathanOliver, you may terminate the recursion explicitly:

```
template <int N>
inline int f()
{
    if (N <= 1)
        return 1;
    return N * f<(N <= 1) ? N : N - 1>();
}
```

Mind, this solution is rather poor (the same terminal condition must be repeated twice), I'm writing this answer merely to show that there are always more ways to solve the problem :- )